# How to show transition of an element that is expanding over nearby content?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Ok, so in theory this should be easy, but it didn't work quite like I would have expected.

I have a list of iline-block elements and upon hovering over them, I want them to expand over nearby elements.

That part is easily accomplished by making the element be positioned absolutely and giving a margin to the next element so it doesn't move...

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it animate with the `transition` property.

Here's an example of what I mean:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="panel">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="moreContentHere">
    Something something darkside.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container .panel {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid red;

    transition:width 300ms;
    -webkit-transition:width 300ms;
    transition:height 300ms;
    -webkit-transition:height 300ms;

    z-index:1;
}

#container .panel:hover {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#eee;
    z-index:2;
}

#container .panel:hover + .panel {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

I've created a jsfiddle for it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yzM9q/2/

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

EDIT after answer: Thanks to vals below, you can view the demo of it working correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/yzM9q/26/

Comment: Nna what is wrong with how it is now?

Comment: It works fine in latest FF. Are you sure your browser supports transitions? Otherwise you need to clarify better what your expected result is.

Comment: I've tried it in the latest version of Chrome and IE10/11 - all of which support transitions (all my other transitions work perfectly).

Comment: I just tried it. The height transition works in Firefox, but the width one doesn't. Neither work in Chrome/IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make transitions in wich you change not numeric properties . (For instance, changing position relative to position absolute. What is the position 50% absolute and 50% relative ?)

So, your CSS should keep the elements position as relative. Now you are taking them out of flow; you can't.  So the alternative is to give the element that is being hovered a negative right margin.

CSS

```
#container {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
}

#container .panel {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;

    transition: width 3s, height 3s, margin-right 3s;
    -webkit-transition: width 3s, height 3s, margin-right 3s;

    z-index:1;
}

#container .panel:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#eee;
    z-index:2;
    margin-right: -100px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzM9q/24/)

I have also  removed the overflow hidden in the parent, just to make the height increase visible.

Comment: Thanks, that's close enough to perfect :).

Comment: People from the future: I just tested this in IE11, Chrome 31 and Firefox 24 and it worked precisely as I wanted :).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

remove `position:absolute` from hovering panel and set `vertical-align:top` to your panels. change your transition to `transition: all 0.3s`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/yzM9q/17/)

```
#container {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container .panel {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-right:1px solid red;

    transition:all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;

    z-index:1;
}

#container .panel:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#eee;
    z-index:2;
}

#container .panel:hover + .panel {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

Comment: I think you  set `margin-left:100px;` for pushing other panels. your can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not do the same thing. I need it to expand in downwards as well as to the side without moving any other elements. Removing 'display:absolute' means that all it does it push other elements out of the way. A simple task that is NOT what I require :).